pipe sticking out of ground
what is this pipe sticking out of ground
Is it possible that it is attached to a buried oil tank?

we do not know you, so we do not know what your concerns are ... perhaps ask how do I determine if it is attached to a buried oil tank?

@jsotola edited to say " is it possible"

Could be a gas line for an obsolete gas grill or pool heater. Could be buried conduit. Could be a lot of things. Unless you can provide more details, or better pictures, we can all only guess.

@joe Is it possible? is a useless question because the answer is always yes

@jsotola "Is it possible" means is it probable.

@joe no it does not mean that  ... if you mean "is it probable?" then ask that, instead of what you asked

Oil tank needs more space and will not be so close to the house.
Oil tank needs two connection. One for refill and one for supply.
The valve on this pipe indicates it is a water valve, and not gas.

@brhans thank you
